# How to divide a string in Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, string

I'm working in Ruby on Rails with Ruby 1.9.3 and Rails 3.2.
I have a long string of words like this:

> foo bar banana nut fruit bar foobar cool awesome stack overflow

I'd like to divide this string into an array. Each element of the array should contain three words out of this string. How would I go about doing this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 11):

```
o = str.split.each_slice(3).map{|a| a.join(" ")}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
string = "foo bar banana nut fruit bar foobar cool awesome stack overflow"
```

This will return an array where each item contains exactly three words from the string:

```
string.scan /\w+\s+\w+\s+\w+/
# => ["foo bar banana", "nut fruit bar", "foobar cool awesome"]
```

If you want the remaining words in an item added to the end as well:

```
string.scan /\w+\s*\w*\s*\w*/
# => ["foo bar banana", "nut fruit bar", "foobar cool awesome", "stack overflow"]
```

Comment: And another one: `string.scan /\w+(?:\s*\w*){2}/`

Answer (score 2):

For your given example

```
x = "foo bar banana nut fruit bar foobar cool awesome stack overflow"
```

The code:

```
result = x.split­(/\s+/).ea­ch_slice(3­).to_a
```

will group them like:

```
[ [foo, bar, banana] [nut, fruit, bar], [foobar, cool, awesome], [stack, overflow] ]
```

Comment: Nice answer, but in your final line, you should use square brackets to make it clear you are constructing an array.  Also, split uses " " by default so you can simplify it by doing `string.split.each_slice(3).to_a`

Comment: After reading the other answers, the user wants the result to be `["foo bar banana", "nut fruit bar", "foobar cool awesome", "stack overflow"]` but your code returns `[["foo", "bar", "banana"], ["nut", "fruit", "bar"], ["foobar", "cool", "awesome"], ["stack", "overflow"]]`